# 'Access Denied' when trying to view Elements in Modx

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am using the [MODx CMS](http://modx.com/). In the box on the left that has the tabs 'Resources' 'Elements' 'Files', I am unable to access the elements because it says Access Denied. I have tried clearing all caches (including my browser cache) and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you sure you got your permissions correct? Under elements are all the template, snippets and chunks. Access to this can be denied by an admin.

Comment: I am the admin.... I had just installed it and was using the default Admin user. This problem no longer persists since I am not using MODx anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the files directly in Modx or through FTP? If it was FTP then its probably a permissions problem. Set the folder to 755.

Comment: I extracted the MODX Revolution zip locally and then uploaded it through FTP, the installation process worked just fine, and I hadn't even done anything with the website files before it started saying 'Access Denied'.